# Ember.js—Why would this.get('model') return a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Here's a jsfiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/YUHLA/5/

This is a problem I ran into while trying to figure out the right pattern for creation of a new record. I can't get the newly created record to save, and I've encountered some odd behavior on the way.

Open the console, and try adding a new post and saving it. Notice three odd occurrences:

1. Calling get('model') on the controller is returning a controller on line 62.
2. On line 65, it's demonstrated that no new models were saved to the fixtures.
3. After creating another post from the post controller and saving it, both posts are saved (line 70).

Here's the javascript:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.store = App.Store.create();

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'title',
    body: 'body'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title two',
    body: 'body two'
  }
];

App.NewPostFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "form",
  templateName: "newPostForm",
  submit: function() {
    this.get('controller').save();
    return false;
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  posts: (function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  }).property()
});

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  sortAscending: false,
  itemController: 'post',
  newPost: function() {
    var post;
    return post = App.Post.createRecord({
      title: '',
      body: '',
      isEditing: true
    });
  }
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  save: function() {
    var temp;
    console.log('Starting to save');
    console.log('this.get(\'model\') =', this.get('model'));
    transaction = App.store.transaction();
    this.set('isEditing', false);
    temp = this.get('model');
    temp.get('store').commit(); 
      Ember.run.next(function(){
          console.log('# fixtures:', App.Post.FIXTURES.length);
          App.Post.createRecord(
              {title: 'post four', body: 'four body'}
          ).get('store').commit()
          Ember.run.next(function(){
             console.log('# fixtures:', App.Post.FIXTURES.length);
          });
      });
  }
});
```

Does this have to do with the fact that I'm creating the model from the posts controller, then saving it in the post controller? If so, how can I get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Does this have to do with the fact that I'm creating the model from the posts controller, then saving it in the post controller?

No.

> 1. Calling get('model') on the controller is returning a controller on line 62.

Right. `PostsController` has specified `itemController: 'post'`, so when the posts template iterates over `{{each post in controller}}` the posts are being wrapped in a `PostController`. That's fine but not in combination with the `{{render}}` helper. When `{{render}}` is used within the each block to `{{render post post}}`, it renders the post template and wraps the specified value (the post variable) in a PostController. So you've got two post controllers wrapping a single post model. Kinda overkill.

> 1. On line 65, it's demonstrated that no new models were saved to the fixtures.

So issue here is that you have two different stores. App.store() is a global variable that was created on line 14. And since it was the first one created, it is the `default store`. It is not related to the one used by your model.

In PostController.save(), `this.get('model')` is returning a controller. And a controller's store is the default store. This is usually the same as the model's store but not in this case. So when you call `get('store').commit()` that is on the default store, which has no models, so nothing happens. If you really had a model (by fixing issue #1) this would have been ok. Or if you'd not created `App.store` it would also have been ok, since in that case the default store would've been the same as your model's store.

Would recommend not creating App.store() yourself, doing this is just confusing and probably not what you want. In general it is best to let ember create things.

> 1. After creating another post from the post controller and saving it, both posts are saved (line 70).

Right. Because commit() was called on App.store(), App.Post's store still had one uncommitted record. App.createRecord({}).get('store').commit() creates a second record in that store then commits both.

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YUHLA/7/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `this.get('model').save()` does not appear to actually make a `POST` request to the backend... is this supposed to be the case? I've made a new fiddle using a transaction, which works on the fiddle, but on my app the same procedure fails to make a `POST` request of the backend. http://jsfiddle.net/YUHLA/9/

Comment: Ahh, turns out I had problems related to specifying "embedded: always" on the post model for its parent model. Switching it to "embedded: load" allowed me to save the post model individually. Now I just have to solve some mysteries related to the keys used in POST requests, and whether they have _id appended to them.

Comment: Great, glad that worked. Re: keys used, best place to look is in the unit test for REST adapter. Just look at the ajax hash being passed for each type of request. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/rest_adapter_test.js